# Rust mismatched types confusing compiler

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, type-mismatch

I've attempted use an impl to handle some strange type logic. Here is a quick reconstruction of the bug:

```
trait Schrodingers {}

struct AliveCat;
impl Schrodingers for Container<AliveCat> {}
struct DeadCat;
impl Schrodingers for Container<DeadCat> {}

struct Container<Cat1>
    where Container<Cat1>: Schrodingers
{
    cat: Cat1,
}

impl<Cat2> Container<Cat2>
    where Container<Cat2>: Schrodingers
{
    fn dead_cat() -> Container<DeadCat> {
        let observed_cat = DeadCat;
        Container { cat: observed_cat }
    }

    fn alive_cat() -> Container<AliveCat> {
        let observed_cat = AliveCat;
        Container { cat: observed_cat }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let dead_cat = Container::dead_cat();
    let alive_cat = Container::alive_cat();
}
```

Which results in the compiler errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:19:26
   |
19 |         Container { cat: observed_cat }
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `DeadCat`
   |
   = note: expected type `Cat2`
   = note:    found type `DeadCat`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:19:9
   |
19 |         Container { cat: observed_cat }
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `DeadCat`, found type parameter
   |
   = note: expected type `Container<DeadCat>`
   = note:    found type `Container<Cat2>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:24:26
   |
24 |         Container { cat: observed_cat }
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `AliveCat`
   |
   = note: expected type `Cat2`
   = note:    found type `AliveCat`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:24:9
   |
24 |         Container { cat: observed_cat }
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `AliveCat`, found type parameter
   |
   = note: expected type `Container<AliveCat>`
   = note:    found type `Container<Cat2>`
```

I have been able to solve this using other methods, but why would the compiler find this confusing?

Comment: Removing the `where` clause on the `struct` itself makes it work, as does qualifying as e.g. `Container::<AliveCat>` in `alive_cat()`.  I think the circular nature of the `struct`/`impl` (both need each other) means the inference fails.

Comment: One could also get rid of `Cat2` altogether and implement `Container<DeadCat>` and `Container<AliveCat>` in separate `impl` blocks. But indeed, the failed inference is surprising.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea qualifying syntax as you mentioned worked with struct declarations,  which fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler was "put against the wall" so to speak.

- The struct `Container<Cat>` is bound to implement `Schrodingers` directly in the struct declaration.

```rust
struct Container<Cat>
where Container<Cat>: Schrodingers
```

- An impl block for `Container<C>` follows it with the same trait bound.
- And finally, we have associated function, such as `alive_cat`, which exists for every `Cat` in `Container<Cat>` where `Container<Cat>: Schrodingers`, yet disregards the type parameter `Cat`, returning a `Container<AliveCat>`.

The compiler then appears to mistakenly infer the parameter type `Cat` as the specific `AliveCat`, even though it does not necessarily true that every `Cat` is always `AliveCat` in that `impl` block, leading to a weird inconsistency, and a misleading error message. As far as the compiler's capabilities are concerned, this could probably work with some tweaks to Rustc, but they might not necessarily happen.

Fortunately, there are easy development guidelines to follow that prevent this issue from ever occurring:

- *Only use trait bounds on structs when absolutely necessary* for your use case. Most of the time these trait bounds can be added to the applicable `impl` clauses instead. Otherwise, any bounds in the struct have to be applied to all subsequent impl blocks, even if that bound is not particularly relevant to the items implemented.
- Write constructors as *associated functions returning `Self`* (or something containing `Self`, such as `Result<Self, _>`, etc). This forces you to write an independent `impl` block for that constructor, with no generic type involved.

```
impl Container<DeadCat> {
    fn dead_cat() -> Self {
        let observed_cat = DeadCat;
        Container { cat: observed_cat }
    }
}

impl Container<AliveCat> {
    fn alive_cat() -> Self {
        let observed_cat = AliveCat;
        Container { cat: observed_cat }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Should trait bounds be duplicated in struct and impl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229332/should-trait-bounds-be-duplicated-in-struct-and-impl)