# How to combine multiple traits as a "trait tuple"?

Tags: rust, traits

I write a lib like:

```
struct Foo<A: AppleTrait, B: BananaTrait, C: CarrotTrait> {...}

impl<A: AppleTrait, B: BananaTrait, C: CarrotTrait> Foo<A,B,C> {...}

struct Bar<A: AppleTrait, B: BananaTrait, C: CarrotTrait> {...}

impl<A: AppleTrait, B: BananaTrait, C: CarrotTrait> Bar<A,B,C> {...}

... and many more...
```

Notice that, things like `<A: AppleTrait, B: BananaTrait, C: CarrotTrait>` always come together, and has appeared many many times. So I want to eliminate such a burden.

Thus I hope I can do something like:

```
define_the_trait_alias ABCTrait = (A: AppleTrait, B: BananaTrait, C: CarrotTrait); // How to do this?

struct Foo<ABC: ABCTrait> {...}

impl<ABC: ABCTrait> Foo<ABC> {...}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You may be able to eliminate a lot of that redundancy by simply omitting the bounds in the places where they are not needed. See (particularly my answer to) [Should trait bounds be duplicated in struct and impl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/3650362)

Comment: @trentcl Thanks! But even if it is omitted, it is still kind of long :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you can use *associated types* rather than generics. For example:

```
trait AbcTrait {
    type Apple: AppleTrait;
    type Banana: BananaTrait;
    type Carrot: CarrotTrait;
}

struct Foo<Abc: AbcTrait> {
    abc: Abc,
}
impl<Abc: AbcTrait> Foo<Abc> {}

struct Bar<Abc: AbcTrait> {
    abc: Abc,
}
impl<Abc: AbcTrait> Bar<Abc> {}
```

When defining a concrete implementation of the trait, you get to choose which concrete type implements which associated type requested by the trait:

```
impl AbcTrait for Salad {
    type Apple = GrannySmith;
    type Banana = Cavendish;
    type Carrot = LunarWhite;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make a super-trait that takes `A`, `B`, and `C` as associated types.
Then you implement that trait for `(A,B,C)` and use that whenever you need to specify types, e.g., `some_func_that_takes_type_params::<(StructA, StructB, StructC)>()`.
To access `A`, `B`, or `C`, you use the associated types instead:

```rust
trait SuperTrait{
    type A: AppleTrait;
    type B: BananaTrait;
    type C: CarrotTrait;
}
impl<A: AppleTrait, B: BananaTrait, C: CarrotTrait> SuperTrait for (A,B,C)
{
    type A = A;
    type B = B;
    type C = C;
}

struct Foo<D: SuperTrait> (std::marker::PhantomData<D>);

impl<D: SuperTrait> Foo<D> {
    /// Example function that returns an A
    fn return_a(&self) -> D::A{
        todo!()
    }
}
```