# How to use iterator item type as struct type parameter

Tags: generics, rust

I have the following code:

```
pub struct Tree<T> {
    root: Box<Node<T>>,
    elements: HashSet<T>,
}

impl<T> Tree<T> {
    pub fn new<I>(source: I) -> Option<Tree<T>>
    where
        I: std::iter::Iterator,
        <I as Iterator>::Item: Hash,
        <I as Iterator>::Item: Eq,
    {
    ...
    }
```

How do I propagate `<I as Iterator>::Item` type to `T`? In other words, how can I write code like this:

`let tree = Tree::new("test".chars());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the Iterator type with `Iterator<Item = T>`. So your code would look like this

```rust
impl<T> Tree<T> {
    pub fn new<I>(source: I) -> Option<Tree<T>>
    where
        I: Iterator<Item = T>,
        T: Hash,
        T: Eq,
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you want your whole Tree to just be able to maintain types that implement the `Hash` and `Eq` trait. You should define that in the implementation.

```rust
impl<T> Tree<T>
where
    T: Hash,
    T: Eq,
{
    pub fn new<I>(source: I) -> Option<Tree<T>>
    where
        I: Iterator<Item = T>,
    {
        None
    }
}
```

That way you won't have to define it for every method.

[Edit]

Removed trait bounds from struct because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229332/should-trait-bounds-be-duplicated-in-struct-and-impl)