# Is it possible to combine type constraints in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, type-constraints

I've been working in quite a number of statically-typed programming languages (C++, Haskell, ...), but am relatively new to Rust.

I often end up writing code like this:

```rust
struct LeafNode<K: Ord + Default + Clone, V: Default + Clone> {
  keys: Vec<K>,
  values: Vec<V>,
}

impl <K: Ord + Default + Clone, V: Default + Clone> LeafNode<K, V> {
  // ...
}
```

There is a lot of repetition here in the type constraints.
This is compounded further when `LeafNode` is used inside something else (say, when building a tree of nodes).
Whenever one of these constraints changes during implementation, there are many places where the code needs to be altered as they are named in many of the different `struct` definitions and `impl` blocks.

Is there a way to create some kind of 'type constraint alias' from `K: Ord + Default + Clone` and `V: Default + Clone`?

If it exists, it probably has some name that I am not aware of, which makes searching for this technique very difficult. Hence this question.

Comment: well, you do not need to constrain the structs, just with the impl would be enough (usually), that would save you a 50% of constrains declaration :)

Comment: @Netwave Interesting! When do and when don't you need to constrain the structs themselves?

Comment: @Qqwy See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229332/should-trait-bounds-be-duplicated-in-struct-and-impl) for more details about when to use bounds on structs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish this by making your own trait that takes the other traits as a bound, then add a blanket implementation for it:

```rust
trait MyConstraint: Ord + Default + Clone {}
impl <T: Ord + Default + Clone> MyConstraint for T {}

struct LeafNode<K: MyConstraint> {
    keys: Vec<K>
}

impl<K: MyConstraint> LeafNode<K> {
    fn keys(&self) -> &[K] {
        &self.keys
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As a complement answer.

You can use [trait alias](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/trait-alias.html) (currently unstable):

```rust
#![feature(trait_alias)]

trait MyConstraint = Ord + Default + Clone;

struct LeafNode<K: MyConstraint> {
    keys: Vec<K>
}

impl<K: MyConstraint> LeafNode<K> {
    fn keys(&self) -> &[K] {
        &self.keys
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aa155860220c9acfd233b074340c6f54)