# Access iterator inside its for loop

Tags: for-loop, rust, iterator, iteration, move-semantics

I am testing a custom bi-directional iterator in rust but i ran into error

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `iter`
   --> src/main.rs:40:13
    |
37  |     let mut iter = BiIterator::from(vec![1, 2, 3]);
    |         -------- move occurs because `iter` has type `BiIterator<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
38  |     for i in iter {
    |              ----
    |              |
    |              `iter` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`
    |              help: consider borrowing to avoid moving into the for loop: `&iter`
39  |         if i == 3 {
40  |             iter.position(0);
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `iter`
```

[reproducable code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=struct%20BiIterator%3CT%3E%20where%20T%3A%20Copy%20%2B%20Clone%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20values%3A%20Vec%3CT%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20pos%3A%20usize%0A%7D%0Aimpl%3CT%3A%20Copy%20%2B%20Clone%3E%20Iterator%20for%20BiIterator%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20Item%20%3D%20T%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20next(%26mut%20self)%20-%3E%20Option%3CSelf%3A%3AItem%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.pos%20%2B%3D%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20let%20None%20%3D%20self.values.get(self.pos-1)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20None%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20let%20Some(val)%20%3D%20self.values.get(self.pos-1)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Some(val.clone())%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20unreachable!()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aimpl%3CT%3A%20Copy%20%2B%20Clone%3E%20BiIterator%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20position(%26mut%20self%2C%20new_pos%3A%20usize)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.pos%20%3D%20new_pos%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20prev(%26mut%20self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.pos%20-%3D%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aimpl%3CT%3A%20Clone%20%2B%20Copy%3E%20std%3A%3Aconvert%3A%3AFrom%3CVec%3CT%3E%3E%20for%20BiIterator%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20from(input%3A%20Vec%3CT%3E)%20-%3E%20Self%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Self%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20values%3A%20input%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pos%3A%200%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20iter%20%3D%20BiIterator%3A%3Afrom(vec!%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20for%20i%20in%20iter%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20i%20%3D%3D%203%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20iter.position(0)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20i)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: Your link does not provide a snippet. That aside, the compiler seems to provide all the information you need.

Comment: In order to post a link to your code on the playground, you need to click the "Share" button. Otherwise you get a link to an empty playground…

Comment: added embedded code

Comment: @Masklinn how do i fix the problem?

Comment: @Masklinn The compiler correctly identifies the problem, but doesn't provide a hint how to fix it. The suggestion it provides to use `for i in &iter` is not useful because it doesn't compile (as `&iter` is not iterable), and wouldn't allow invoking `position()` inside the loop anyway. The proper solution is obvious to someone experienced in Rust, but not so to a beginner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `for` loop is taking ownership of the iterator. To use the iterator inside the loop body, you need to desugar the `for` loop into `while let`:

```
while let Some(i) = iter.next() {
    if i == 3 {
        iter.position(0);
    }
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

If you want to make your iterator usable from a `for` loop, you'll need to invest a bit of extra effort. You can implement `Iterator` for `&BiIterator`, and use [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) for `pos`, so `position()` can take `&self`:

```
// don't need RefCell because we're just mutating a number
use std::cell::Cell;

struct BiIterator<T> {
    values: Vec<T>,
    pos: Cell<usize>,
}

impl<T: Clone> Iterator for &BiIterator<T> {
    type Item = T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.pos.set(self.pos.get() + 1);
        self.values.get(self.pos.get() - 1).cloned()
    }
}

impl<T> BiIterator<T> {
    pub fn position(&self, new_pos: usize) {
        self.pos.set(new_pos);
    }
    pub fn prev(&mut self) {
        self.pos.set(self.pos.get() - 1);
    }
}

impl<T> std::convert::From<Vec<T>> for BiIterator<T> {
    fn from(input: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        Self {
            values: input,
            pos: Cell::new(0),
        }
    }
}
```

With these changes you can finally use `for i in &iter` as per the compiler's original suggestion:

```
fn main() {
    let iter = BiIterator::from(vec![1, 2, 3]);
    for i in &iter {
        if i == 3 {
            iter.position(0);
        }
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

The above implements some additional changes:

- no need for the `Copy` bound on `T`, since you're only cloning it. Any `T` that is `Copy` is automatically `Clone`, and cloning it can be expected to just perform the cheap copy.
- bounds are [almost never needed on the struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66369912/1600898); put them just on the `impl` instead.
- replace the if/else if let/else chain with a `match` or, better yet, with `Option::cloned()`.

Comment: Side note: While `Copy: Clone`, `v.clone()` where `v` is `Copy` is **not necessarily the same** as copying. And while different behaviors are strongly discouraged, compilation may take more time because it needs to optimize `clone()` into a copy and may even not succeed in that.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Good point! I've adjusted the wording of the last paragraph to reflect that possibility (small though it might be). As for the second part, I fully expect optimizing `clone()` into a copy to work for all types where `Clone` is derived along with `Copy`.But in any case, requiring *both* `Copy` and `Clone` probably doesn't make sense - if the code wanted to require `Copy` for better optimization, then it should just use `*val` rather than `val.clone()`, and omit the `Clone` bound.