# Rust Cacher with HashMap Chapter 13

Tags: rust, hashmap, closures

As suggested in Chapter 13, I am trying to implement the Cacher with a HashMap. Unlike some of the other questions asked, I am trying to follow the aproach taken by the author and use Option as value in the Cacher.

```
struct Cacher<T>
    where T: Fn(u32) -> u32, //struct needs to know Type of closure(aka calc)
{
    calc: T, 
    value: Option<HashMap<u32, u32>> 
}

impl<T> Cacher<T>
where T: Fn(u32) -> u32,{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T>{
        Cacher {
            calc: calculation,
            value: None
        }
    }

    fn value(&mut self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
        match &mut self.value {
            Some(map) => {
                let v = map.entry(arg).or_insert((self.calc)(arg));
                *v
            },

            None => {
                let mut map = HashMap::new();
                let v = map.insert(arg, (self.calc)(arg)).unwrap();
                self.value = Some(map);
                v
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code compiles but even running a simple:

```
let mut expensive_res = Cacher::new( |num| {
        println!("calculating slowly....{}", num);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    num + 100
    });
println!("{}", expensive_res.value(1));
```

I get an Panic when running it.
**thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value'**.
Any suggestions? Why is unwrap here a None?
Many thanks

Comment: [Don't put bounds on the struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66369912/7884305).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```rust
> let mut map = HashMap::new();
> let v = map.insert(arg, (self.calc)(arg)).unwrap();
> self.value = Some(map);
> v
> ```

I think you're confused about what `HashMap::insert` returns: it returns *the previous value for the key, if any* (which is why it's an `Option`).

So when you've just created an empty map and you insert into it for the first time... it returns `None` because there *can not* have been an existing value there. Therefore this codepath can only panic.

incidentally the code is overcomplicated due to the *completely unnecessary* `Option<HashMap>`:

> The hash map is initially created with a capacity of 0, so it will not allocate until it is first inserted into.

So putting aside the idea that this would serve any role as a temporal optimisation, it doesn't even do so, because allocation is delayed until first insertion.

There is an other issue, on both codepaths: Rust is an eager language, which means:

```rust
let v = map.entry(arg).or_insert((self.calc)(arg));
```

is equivalent to:

```rust
let mut entry = map.entry(arg);
let default = (self.calc)(arg);
let v = entry.or_insert(default);
```

so you're running the computation *even when it's already in the cache*, aka instead of trading memory for CPU this implementation just wastes memory.

Comment: thank you very much. Indeed, looking at the documentation of insert I missed that point. And similarly, given that HashMap created with 0 capacity it does mean that there is no point in using Option in this case. And thank you for pointing out the last issue as well. I don't want to allocate/run default every time. 
Many thanks!