# How to get a rust nested generic

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to write a generic struct that will hold a collection and the sum of all the inserted values into that collection.

That is a generic type that keeps the sum of all added values to it.

```
pub struct SummedCollection<T>
where 
    T::Item: std::ops::Add<Output=T::Item> + std::ops::Div<Output=T::Item>
{
    sum: T::Item,
    values: T,
}

impl<T> SummedCollection<T> { 
    pub fn new() -> Self{
        SummedCollection {
            sum: T::Item::default(),
            values: T::new(),
        }
    }
    pub fn push(&mut self, value: T::Item) {
        self.values.push(value);
        self.sum = self.sum + value;
    }
    pub fn sum(&self) -> T::Item {
        self.sum
    }
}
```

The intended use would be:

```
let v: SummedCollection<Vec<i32>> = SummedCollection::new();
v.push(5);
v.push(10);
```

I would then expect: `v.sum() == 15`.

I get an error "^^^^ associated type `Item` not found" on each assurance of T::Item,
what do I need to do to access the nested generic (the i32 in my example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know `T::Item`. You intended `T` to be some collection type, but didn't tell it to the compiler, so it doesn't know that.

You have to tell the compiler `T` implements some collection trait. A trait like that doesn't exist in the standard library, but you can easily write your own:

```rust
pub trait Collection {
    type Item;
    fn push(&mut self, value: Self::Item);
}

// Example implementation, you can implement the trait for any collection type you wish
impl<T> Collection for Vec<T> {
    type Item = T;
    fn push(&mut self, value: T) {
        self.push(value);
    }
}

pub struct SummedCollection<T: Collection> {
    sum: T::Item,
    values: T,
}

impl<T> SummedCollection<T>
where
    T: Collection + Default,
    T::Item: Default + Copy + std::ops::Add<Output = T::Item> + std::ops::Div<Output = T::Item>,
{
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        SummedCollection {
            sum: T::Item::default(),
            values: T::default(),
        }
    }
    pub fn add(&mut self, value: T::Item) {
        self.values.push(value);
        self.sum = self.sum + value;
    }
    pub fn sum(&self) -> T::Item {
        self.sum
    }
}
```

Note I made some additional changes:

- Required `T::Item` to be `Copy` and `Default`. It may be possible to work around this need, but it's easy this way.
- Required `T: Default` and changed `T::new()` to `T::default()`, since we already have a default-constructible trait - no need to reinvent the wheel.
- Moved some of the bounds from the struct to the impl, since [it is better this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229332/should-trait-bounds-be-duplicated-in-struct-and-impl).

**Edit:** Thanks for @mcarton that pointed out that we can use [`Extend`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html) for that:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct SummedCollection<Collection, T> {
    sum: T,
    values: Collection,
}

impl<Collection, T> SummedCollection<Collection, T>
where
    Collection: Extend<T> + Default,
    T: Default + Copy + std::ops::Add<Output = T> + std::ops::Div<Output = T>,
{
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        SummedCollection {
            sum: T::default(),
            values: Collection::default(),
        }
    }
    pub fn add(&mut self, value: T) {
        self.values.extend(std::iter::once(value));
        self.sum = self.sum + value;
    }
    pub fn sum(&self) -> T {
        self.sum
    }
}
```

But note that because it requires an additional generic parameter it will affect users: instead of

```rust
let v: SummedCollection<Vec<i32>> = SummedCollection::new();
```

You'll have to write

```rust
let v: SummedCollection<Vec<i32>, _> = SummedCollection::new();
```

Or explicitly, of course:

```rust
let v: SummedCollection<Vec<i32>, i32> = SummedCollection::new();
```

Comment: Your `Collection` trait could just as well be [`Extend`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html).

Comment: @mcarton Not a complete replacement, but thanks. Edited.