# Rust struct field that implements multiple traits

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a struct that holds a field which implements two traits:

```rust
use meilisearch_sdk::document::Document;
use serde::{Serialize,Deserialize};


trait DeserializableDocument<'a>: Deserialize<'a> + Document{}


#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct KafkaMessage<'a, DeserializableDocument>{
    Data: &'a DeserializableDocument,
}
```

Where the following struct would satisfy `Data`:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct User {
    ID: String,
    Firstname: String,
    Lastname: String,
}

impl Document for User {
    type UIDType = String;
    fn get_uid(&self) -> &Self::UIDType { &self.ID }
}
```

However upon trying to define the empty trait object `DeserializableDocument` I get the following error:

```
type annotations needed

cannot infer type for type parameter `Self`

note: cannot satisfy `Self: <my-project>::documents::_::_serde::Deserialize<'a>`
```

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version="1.0",   features = ["derive"] }
meilisearch-sdk = "0.15"
```

What is the correct way to approach this?

### Edit 1:

When restructured according to @ChayimFriedman answer and @SebastianRedl comment:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct KafkaMessage<D> where D: Document {
    Data: D,
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
type annotations needed for `std::option::Option<D>`

consider giving `__field1` the explicit type `std::option::Option<D>`, where the type parameter `D` is specified
```

Ofcourse, specifying `D: Option<D>` doesn't resolve it either.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that we can copy and paste to reproduce the problem, or _at the very least_ include the full compiler output.

Comment: @cdhowie this is literally this minimal example, and the compiler output...

Comment: You use the same name for the trait `DeserializableDocument` and the generic parameter `DeserializableDocument`. Did you mean to write `struct KafkaMessage<'a, D> where D: DeserializableDocuemnt<'a>` or something like that?

Comment: "However upon trying to define the empty trait object DeserializableDocument" - `DeserializableDocument` is a trait, not a trait object. You definitely have quite a few technical terms confused. Your might want to re-read the relevant parts of the documentation about traits and generics.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I think you are correct, I changed the syntax but still get the error. The objective remains the same, I want `Data` to implement `Deserialize` and `Document`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Document`](https://docs.rs/meilisearch-sdk/latest/meilisearch_sdk/document/trait.Document.html) already includes the `Self: DeserializeOwned` bound, and [`DeserializeOwned`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html) is basically `for<'a> Deserialize<'a>` (and also has this bound). So you basically requested the compiler to satisfy:

```rust
trait DeserializableDocument<'a>: Deserialize<'a> + for<'b> Deserialize<'b> {}
```

Or, generalized:

```rust
trait Trait<'a> {}
trait Foo<'a>: Trait<'a> + for<'b> Trait<'b> {}
```

[This produces the same error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=94818406f96dfe5f1a086ccd01cf35a7):

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
 --> src/lib.rs:2:16
  |
2 | trait Foo<'a>: Trait<'a> + for<'b> Trait<'b> {}
  |                ^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `Self`
  |
  = note: cannot satisfy `Self: Trait<'a>`
```

<s>I don't know why this error happens (it sound trivial to prove that if `Trait<'a>` is implemented for *any* lifetime `'a` then `Trait<'a>` is implemented for *some* lifetime `'a`)</s> **Edit:** this is a compiler bug: [#84435](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/84435)<sup>1</sup>, but since `DeserializeOwned` implies any lifetime for `Deserialize<'a>`, you can just omit that bound:

```rust
trait DeserializableDocument: Document {}
```

**Edit:** As for your new error, it is exactly the same reason. The `#[derive(Deserialize)]` is expanding to something like:

```rust
impl<'de, D> Deserialize<'de> for KafkaMessage<D>
where
    D: Document,
    D: Deserialize<'de>,
{
    // ...
}
```

Which like we already learn, is essentially the same as:

```rust
impl<'de, D> Deserialize<'de> for KafkaMessage<D>
where
    D: for<'a> Deserialize<'a>,
    D: Deserialize<'de>,
{
    // ...
}
```

And again we see the conflict.

The best advice I can give is to just not put the `where` bounds on the struct, but rather on the `impl`s. Putting bounds on the struct is [a bad idea anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/7884305).

---

<sub>1. Thanks @steffahn for helping to find it out [at users.rust-lang.org](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/strange-type-annotations-needed-error/74117/4?u=chrefr)!</sub>

Comment: I've made progress thanks to your answer, but it's not quite complete, I've updated my question

Comment: @CertainlyNotAdrian Edited to explain. Though, being a different error, I think you should've post a new question about it.

Comment: @CertainlyNotAdrian, do not update (expand) questions if it is not for a better explanation. For new content is better to open a newly related one :)