# str to object deserialisation lifetime related issue

Tags: serialization, rust, deserialization

```
struct S1<T> 
{
    pub data: T
}
    
impl<'a, T> S1<T> where T: Deserialize<'a> {
    fn update() {
        let str_json = String::new(); // let's assume read from file
        self.data = serve_json::from_str(&str_json).unwrap();
    } 
}
```

this function will produce lifetime related issue due to incorrect specifier. What is the best way to overcome the problem?

Comment: If you change impl to `impl<T> S1<T> where T: DeserializeOwned`, it compiles. Is that sufficient for your needs?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72671494/11527076) to your other question.

Answer (score 0):

`Deserialize` does *not* necessarily create a copy of the data in `str_json`. There might be large text sections in `str_json` that get referenced in the final `T` instead of being copied into it. That means, the lifetime of the final `self.data` is identical to the one from `str_json`, as it might potentially borrow data from `str_json`. That is also the reason why you have to specify the lifetime `'a` in the first place.

Now in your case, the problem is that `self.data` gets stored in `self`, while `str_json` gets dropped at the end of `update()`. But `self.data` might still reference data from `str_json`, so the compiler rightfully complains.

I think what you actually wanted to achieve is that the data from `str_json` gets copied *into* `self.data` instead of just being referenced. For that behaviour, you have the wrong trait, and what you actually want is `DeserializeOwned`:

```rust
use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;

struct S1<T> {
    pub data: T,
}

impl<T> S1<T>
where
    T: DeserializeOwned,
{
    fn update(&mut self) {
        let str_json = String::new(); // let's assume read from file
        self.data = serde_json::from_str(&str_json).unwrap();
    }
}
```