# Writing a trait bound only once for generic struct in Rust

Tags: generics, rust

I have a generic struct in Rust and want the parameter K to have some trait bounds like so:

```
pub struct IndexStore<K, V>
where
    K: std::cmp::Eq + Hash + Debug,
{
    m: HashMap<K, V>,
    name: Option<String>,
}
```

But now, whenever I write an impl block I find myself needing to write the trait bound out again. If not I get errors like "*the trait bound `K: std::cmp::Eq` is not satisfied*". Here are some examples of my impl blocks:

```
impl<K, V> Deref for IndexStore<K, V>
where
    K: std::cmp::Eq + Hash + Debug,
{
    type Target = HashMap<K, V>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.m
    }
}

impl<K, V> DerefMut for IndexStore<K, V>
where
    K: std::cmp::Eq + Hash + Debug,
{
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.m
    }
}

impl<K, V> FromIterator<(K, V)> for IndexStore<K, V>
where
    K: std::cmp::Eq + Hash + Debug,
{
    fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item = (K, V)>>(iter: I) -> Self {
        IndexStore {
            m: iter.into_iter().collect(),
            name: None,
        }
    }
}
```

How can I only specify the trait bound once in the struct definition without repeating it in every impl block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [RFC 2089, "Extended implied bounds"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44491) however it is not yet implemented, and it is not clear what will be the shape of the feature.

However, [you should not put bounds on the struct unless the struct will not compile without them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/7884305), so this is likely not a good idea anyway.

On nightly, you can use a [trait alias](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41517) to shorten the bound:

```rust
#![feature(trait_alias)]

trait EqHashDebug = std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash + std::fmt::Debug;

pub struct IndexStore<K, V> {
    m: HashMap<K, V>,
    name: Option<String>,
}

impl<K: EqHashDebug, V> Deref for IndexStore<K, V> {
    type Target = HashMap<K, V>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.m
    }
}

impl<K: EqHashDebug, V> DerefMut for IndexStore<K, V> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.m
    }
}

impl<K: EqHashDebug, V> FromIterator<(K, V)> for IndexStore<K, V> {
    fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item = (K, V)>>(iter: I) -> Self {
        IndexStore {
            m: iter.into_iter().collect(),
            name: None,
        }
    }
}
```

On stable, you can emulate a trait alias with a trait with a a blanket implementation:

```rust
trait EqHashDebug: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash + std::fmt::Debug {}
impl<T: ?Sized + std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash + std::fmt::Debug> EqHashDebug for T {}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the trait alias suggestion really helps me!