# How to express vacuous trait bound in rust?

Tags: rust

Suppose I want to write a HashMap wrapper. My attempt:

```rust
struct Wrapper<K,V> where HashMap<K,V>: Default{
   value: HashMap<K,V>
}
```

I want K,V to implicitly have whatever bounds that make HashMap<K,V> valid. Is there a trait that is better than Default that better communicates this intention? Something like HashMap<K,V>: True ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HashMap` is valid, type-wise, for any key/value types. You can call `HashMap::new` with any types.

Obviously this isn't very useful, but there's no type-level usefulness measure, so you can't work around copying the trait bounds. Nearly all of `HashMap`'s methods are in [this impl block](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#impl-HashMap%3CK,+V,+S%3E-1), so you can just copy the bounds of that one.

```rs
where K: Eq + Hash
```

You should put this only on the impl block that requires it and not on the struct, if possible. [See this question for an explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/6274355) You may also need to put bounds on each method, like what `HashMap` does.

```rs
where
    K: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Hash + Eq + ?Sized,
```