# Restrict generic to "string like" while being either `&str` or `String`

Tags: rust

I have some code, but the problem boilds down to this:

```rust
pub struct Thing<S>
where S: AsRef<str> // im using AsRef here but the point is just that `S` is string-like
{
   this: S
}

impl<S> Default for Thing<S>
where S: AsRef<str> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            this: "i am a `&'static str`"
        }
    }
}
```

Cargo says:

```
expected type parameter `S`
        found reference `&'static str`
```

I get that the problem is something to do with it being a reference to an `str`, I just don't really know what to do about it. How do I restrict a generic to being "string like", while making sure that said generic can be at least an `&str` or a `String`?

Comment: The main question is: What should `Thing<String>::default` return? Writing this would be allowed in your current code, but the `this` value would clearly not be a `String` because it internally gets instantiated with a `&'static str`. I feel like this is an XY-problem, and what you actually want is an enum. Although I'm of course missing context, so I don't know.

Comment: @Finomnis the general idea is a config for the lib, one of the values being a "name" which I want to be some kind of string. The default implementation will just return what I think are sensible defaults for people who don't want to fill all the values (there are a lot)

Comment: Be aware that the actual type of the generic is determined at **compile time**. I'm not sure using a generic here is the right choice. You won't ever be able to use the default unless you specify at the struct where you are using it that it will be a `Thing<&'static str>`, and then it will no longer accept anything else than a `&'static str` ever again. Are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 4):

In this situation, you don't want a generic at all. The function doesn't produce a generic `Self`, it produces a specific one.

```rs
impl Default for Thing<&'static str> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            this: "i am a `&'static str`"
        }
    }
}
```

Also, [don't put trait bounds on struct definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/6274355).

Comment: Generally I don't do trait bounds on struct definitions but this struct is intended to be built manually so I can't restrict it from a function

Comment: @salmon It is still not necessary unless it implements `Drop`. There is no harm in creating something that can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid future problems with the lifetime, you can also solve the task by using `String` instead of `&str`:

```
pub struct Thing<S: Into<String>> {
    this: S,
}

impl Default for Thing<String> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            this: "I am a String".to_string(),
        }
    }
}
```