# How do I use async closures in enums without a where clause?

Tags: rust

I want to do the following but without a where clause as the generics get out of hand and I don't even know how to properly fill them out. Is there a way to do this without the use of generics?

```
pub enum  PreparedMigration<F, Fut> where 
F: FnOnce(&DatabaseConnection) -> Fut,
Fut: Future<Output = bool>{
    Simple(String),
    Statement(Statement),
    Closure(F)
}
```

Comment: You should usually not put trait bounds on structs/enums: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/6274355 You may also want to create a trait that encompasses these bounds into one, depending on how you use this type.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic dispatch could be used here instead to avoid generics, if you're okay with heap allocating the closures and futures:

```
pub enum PreparedMigration {
    Simple(String),
    Statement(Statement),
    Closure(Pin<Box<dyn FnOnce(&DatabaseConnection) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = bool>>>>>)
}
```

You'll probably also need to add `Send` bounds if you're using a multithreaded scheduler.

Comment: Typically you'd wrap the `Box` in a `Pin` in cases like this as well, otherwise the caller has to.