# rust lifetime problem when using `&str` in struct with `new` method

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use the `&str` type in one of my struct.
this struct has an async `new` method so I can read the parameter from the env file and create an instance. the problem is I can't fix the lifetime of it.

```rs
pub struct AppContext<'a>{
    pub site_url: &'a str
}
impl<'a> AppContext<'a>{
    pub async fn new()->AppContext<'a>{
        //fill website url base on env variables
        let site_url =  std::env::var("WEBSITE_URL").unwrap_or("http://localhost:3000".to_string());
        AppContext{
            site_url: site_url.as_str()
        }
    }
}
```

it keep telling me `cannot return value referencing local variable 'site_url' returns a value referencing data owned by the current function`
how can I fix this?

Comment: Store `String` and not `&str`. In fact, while you're a beginner, my recommendation is to avoid lifetimes. Only store owned types in structs. This will require you to clone sometimes, but this is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this code will work for you.

Your `AppContext` will still work for normal reference to `str`, but it will also support *smart pointers* like `String` which own their values.
This allows `AppContext` to be either owner or borrower of `str`. You will always choose the more convenient option.

```
    use std::ops::Deref;
    
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct AppContext<D: Deref<Target = str>> {
        pub site_url: D,
    }
    
    impl<D: Deref<Target = str>> AppContext<D> {
        pub fn new(site_url: D) -> Self {
            Self { site_url }
        }
    }
    
    fn get_website_url() -> String {
        std::env::var("WEBSITE_URL").unwrap_or_else(|_| "http://localhost:3000".to_string())
    }
    
    fn main() {
        let owning_obj = AppContext::new(get_website_url());
        let dependant_obj = AppContext::new("https://Your/hardcoded/page.com");
        dbg!(owning_obj, dependant_obj);
    }
```

Also, you may consider type erasure with `Box<dyn Deref<str>>` to make `AppContext` non-generic.

Comment: I corrected my code. I tried to add `DerefMut`, but it would make it impossible to use string literals.

Comment: Note that `AppContext` should not require the `Deref<Target = str>` bound on the struct. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66369912/6655004) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you were allowed to do this, it would result in a use-after-free error. Note that `site_url` has type `String`. The function `String::as_str` takes a `&'a String` and outputs a `&'a str`. In other words, the reference to the `str` is only valid for as long as the reference to the underlying `String` is.

Since `site_url` is a local variable, it will go out of scope at the end of the block where it's defined. This means that the `&site_url` which is used in `site_url.as_str()` is only valid until that time. After that point, the string will be freed.

```rust
    pub async fn new()->AppContext<'a>{
        //fill website url base on env variables
        let site_url =  std::env::var("WEBSITE_URL").unwrap_or("http://localhost:3000".to_string());
        AppContext{
            site_url: site_url.as_str()
        }
        // site_url is a local variable that goes out of scope here. This is 
        // when site_url will be dropped, and the reference to it will no longer be valid
    }
```

This means that by the time you're actually using the `AppContext` that the `new` function eventually produces, the `&'a str` inside it will be invalid!

One solution is to redefine `AppContext` so `site_url` is a `String`, not a `&str`.

Comment: sure, this is a way but I prefer &str over string if possible. if there is no other way to do this I have to change it's type as you say

Comment: @javadbat If you really want to deal with `&str`, then pass the value in as a parameter of `new`.