# Why does some code with type parameters used only in trait bounds compile without PhantomData?

Tags: rust

This code doesn't compile ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=555f10364c3ba0e68dddb7c9bf3c202b)):

```rust
struct Mapper<T, U, F>
where
    F: Fn(T) -> U,
{
    mapper: F,
    // _t: PhantomData<T>,
    // _u: PhantomData<U>,
}

impl<T, U, F> Mapper<T, U, F>
where
    F: Fn(T) -> U,
{
    fn new(mapper: F) -> Self {
        Self {
            mapper,
            // _t: PhantomData,
            // _u: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    fn call(&self, t: T) -> U {
        (self.mapper)(t)
    }
}
```

The compiler says

```
error[E0392]: parameter `T` is never used
 --> src/main.rs:3:15
  |
3 | struct Mapper<T, U, F>
  |               ^ unused parameter
  |
  = help: consider removing `T`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `PhantomData`
  = help: if you intended `T` to be a const parameter, use `const T: usize` instead

error[E0392]: parameter `U` is never used
 --> src/main.rs:3:18
  |
3 | struct Mapper<T, U, F>
  |                  ^ unused parameter
  |
  = help: consider removing `U`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `PhantomData`
  = help: if you intended `U` to be a const parameter, use `const U: usize` instead
```

However, this code compiles though I add `PhantomData` only for `T`:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Mapper<T, U, F>
where
    F: Fn(T) -> U,
{
    mapper: F,
    _t: PhantomData<T>,
    // _u: PhantomData<U>,
}

impl<T, U, F> Mapper<T, U, F>
where
    F: Fn(T) -> U,
{
    fn new(mapper: F) -> Self {
        Self {
            mapper,
            _t: PhantomData,
            // _u: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    fn call(&self, t: T) -> U {
        (self.mapper)(t)
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if I add `PhantomData` only for `U`, the code doesn't compile:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Mapper<T, U, F>
where
    F: Fn(T) -> U,
{
    mapper: F,
    // _t: PhantomData<T>,
    _u: PhantomData<U>,
}

impl<T, U, F> Mapper<T, U, F>
where
    F: Fn(T) -> U,
{
    fn new(mapper: F) -> Self {
        Self {
            mapper,
            // _t: PhantomData,
            _u: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    fn call(&self, t: T) -> U {
        (self.mapper)(t)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mapper = Mapper::new(|a: usize| -> isize { -(a as isize) });
    println!("{}", mapper.call(3));
}
```

Why?

Comment: Report a bug (for the `U` error).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Just opened an issue: [*Unused parameter error occurs for an actually used type parameter. #114527*](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/114527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the error is incorrect. This makes more sense with a regular trait with generics and associated types.

This compiles.

```rs
use std::ops::Add;

pub struct A<X, Z>
where
    X: Add<Output = Z>,
{
    pub adder: X,
}
```

This does not.

```rs
pub struct A<X, Y>
where
    X: Add<Y>,
{
    pub adder: X,
}
```

This gives two errors, even though `Y` is the only actual error.

```rs
pub struct A<X, Y, Z>
where
    X: Add<Y, Output = Z>,
{
    pub adder: X,
}
```

And if you look at the definition of [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), you'll see that the parameter is a generic, while the return is an associated type (on [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html)). So associated types count as usage, while generics do not.

Note that this is not an issue for most code, since you [shouldn't put trait bounds on structs except in specific cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/6274355). You would simply use unbound generics for any generic fields, and then bind them to traits in the implementation. This compiles fine.

```rs
pub struct A<X> {
    pub adder: X,
}

impl<X> A<X>
{
    pub fn new<Y>(x: X, y: Y) -> Self 
    where
        X: Add<Y, Output = X>,
    {
        Self {
            adder: x + y,
        }
    }
}
```

There may still be need for `PhantomData`, especially if you need to implement a certain trait, but in most cases you can rearrange your generics to avoid it.

Comment: Following your advice, I tried to refactor my code to avoid `PhantomData`. Here's the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f3818fb57157dd6741f34e773395e2e4), but this results in another kind of redundancy (repetition of `where` clause). Do you have any idea to write this in a more elegant way?

Comment: @ynn you don't need `new` to be generic at all. Just make it `fn new(mapper: F) -> Self`

Comment: It works ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bd9c94a4d7120925e175595b2cd8928f)). Thank you.