# Rust ownership issue

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

I want to implement Singly Linked List concept by Rust.
However, there is issue when I implement push_front function.

Error message is like below.
cannot move out of `self.head` as enum variant `Some` which is behind a mutable reference

How can I fix this issue?

```
//! Singly linked list.
//!
//! Consult <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-01-box.html>.

use std::fmt::Debug;

/// Node of the list.
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node<T: Debug> {
    /// Value of current node.
    pub value: T,

    /// Pointer to the next node. If it is `None`, there is no next node.
    pub next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<T: Debug> Node<T> {
    /// Creates a new node.
    pub fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        Self { value, next: None }
    }
}

/// A singly-linked list.
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct SinglyLinkedList<T: Debug> {
    /// Head node of the list. If it is `None`, the list is empty.
    head: Option<Node<T>>,
}

impl<T: Debug> Default for SinglyLinkedList<T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new()
    }
}

impl<T: Debug> SinglyLinkedList<T> {
    /// Creates a new list.
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { head: None }
    }

    /// Adds the given node to the front of the list.
    pub fn push_front(&mut self, value: T) {
        let mut new_node = Node::new(value);
        new_node.next = match self.head {
            Some(head_node) => Some(Box::new(head_node)),
            None => None
        };
        self.head = Some(new_node);
    }
}
```

```
error: cannot move out of `self.head` as enum variant `Some` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/lib.rs:46:31
   |
46 |         new_node.next = match self.head {
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^
47 |             Some(head_node) => Some(Box::new(head_node)),
   |                  ---------
   |                  |
   |                  data moved here
   |                  move occurs because `head_node` has type `Node<T>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
help: consider borrowing here
   |
46 |         new_node.next = match &self.head {
```

Comment: I hope you won't try after to implement a doubly linked list. Just a note.

Comment: Nitpick: [Putting bounds on the struct is almost always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229332/should-trait-bounds-be-duplicated-in-struct-and-impl). Here it's also needlessly restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

You know than in a moment you're going to replace `self.head` anyway so we can move out of it now, but the compiler doesn't know this. You can help the compiler by using [`take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take):

```rust
/// Adds the given node to the front of the list.
pub fn push_front(&mut self, value: T) {
    let mut new_node = Node::new(value);
    new_node.next = match self.head.take() {
        Some(head_node) => Some(Box::new(head_node)),
        None => None,
    };
    self.head = Some(new_node);
}
```

The `match` can also be shortened using [`map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map):

```rust
/// Adds the given node to the front of the list.
pub fn push_front(&mut self, value: T) {
    let mut new_node = Node::new(value);
    new_node.next = self.head.take().map(Box::new);
    self.head = Some(new_node);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=25b05c6da62b8b9e2234681e01187e22).

Comment: Thank you! using map and take is great!!