# Rust: a function to produce a generic struct

Tags: generics, rust

I'm new with Rust.

I've encountered a problem with generics. I want a function to construct a generic structure from two lamda-expression (closure). I've got code:

```rust
    use num::complex::Complex;
    type Complex<f64> = ClxD;

    struct Problem<F, D> where F: Fn(ClxD) -> ClxD, D: Fn(ClxD) -> ClxD, {
        pub f: F,
        pub f_derive: D,
    }

    impl<F,D> Problem<F,D> where F: Fn(ClxD) -> ClxD, D: Fn(ClxD) -> ClxD, {
        fn new(f:F, f_derive: D) -> Self {
            Self {f, f_derive}
        } 
    }
```

Now I need a function to produce for me the quadratic polynom with two roots as a **Problem struct**. According to the Rust type-checking ideas I have to explicitly state the return type of a function. **And here I've stuck!**

```rust
    fn make_quadratic_problem(root_1: ClxD, root_2: ClxD) -> Problem<???,???> {
        Problem::new(|c| { (c - root_1) * (c - root_2) }, |c| { c * c - (root_1 + root_2) }
    }
```

Is there any workaround?

P.S. In case it may help, there is original C++ code:

```c++
template<typename T, typeanme D>
struct Problem {
    F f;
    D f_derive;
    Problem(F &&f, D &&f_derive): f(std::forward<F>(f)), f_derive(std::forward<D>(f_derive)) { }
};

auto make_quadratic_problem(std::complex<double> const &root_1, std::complex<double> const &root_2) {
    return Problem(
        [root_1, root_2](std::complex<double> const &c) { return (c - root_1) * (c - root_2); },
        [root_1, root_2](std::complex<double> const &c) { return c * c - (root_1 + root_2); }
    );
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the trait bounds on `Problem` and `impl Problem`. The type and the `new()` function work just fine for any type parameters, so there is no need to constraing them. You may also want to define a custom trait so you don't have to type `Fn(ClxD) -> ClxD` all the time.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I use the structure to call on it's components. Thus I believe I have to impose a restiction. Am I right?

Comment: You only need to bound the types on the functions that actually call the function pointers. You don't need to put these trait bounds everywhere. See [Should trait bounds be duplicated in struct and impl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229332/should-trait-bounds-be-duplicated-in-struct-and-impl) for further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the [`impl Trait`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/impl_trait.html#as-a-return-type) form in the return type.

Moreover, we need [`move` on the closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html#capturing-references-or-moving-ownership) in order to prevent from referencing `root_1` and `root_2`, which won't exist after `make_quadratic_problem()`.

Because `num::complex::Complex<f64>` is `Copy`, the copy happens naturally (instead of moving), as with integers or reals.

Note that you reversed the `type` declaration.

```rust
type ClxD = Complex<f64>;

fn make_quadratic_problem(
    root_1: ClxD,
    root_2: ClxD,
) -> Problem<impl Fn(ClxD) -> ClxD, impl Fn(ClxD) -> ClxD> {
    Problem::new(
        move |c| (c - root_1) * (c - root_2),
        move |c| c * c - (root_1 + root_2),
    )
}
```