# boxed object doesn't have a size known at compile-time

Tags: rust

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo(&self);
}

struct A {}

impl MyTrait for A {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("A");
    }
}

struct B {}

impl MyTrait for B{
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("B");
    }
}

enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B,
}

fn create_object(my_enum: MyEnum) -> Box<dyn MyTrait> {
    let boxed_value: Box<dyn MyTrait> = match my_enum {
        MyEnum::A => Box::new(A{}),
        MyEnum::B => Box::new(B{}),
    };
    boxed_value
}

struct C<Allocator>
where Allocator: MyTrait + ?Sized {
    a: Box<Allocator>,
}

impl<Allocator> C<Allocator>
where Allocator: MyTrait {
    pub fn new(a: Box<Allocator>) -> Self {
        Self {a: a}
    }
}


fn main() {
    let boxed_value = create_object(MyEnum::A);
    C::new(boxed_value);
}
```

compile error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn MyTrait` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:49:12
   |
49 |     C::new(boxed_value);
   |     ------ ^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |     |
   |     required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn MyTrait`
note: required by a bound in `C::<Allocator>::new`
  --> src/main.rs:39:6
   |
39 | impl<Allocator> C<Allocator>
   |      ^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `C::<Allocator>::new`
40 | where Allocator: MyTrait {
41 |     pub fn new(a: Box<Allocator>) -> Self {
   |            --- required by a bound in this associated function

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to previous error
```

I am not sure what this means. Trait object doesn't have a fixed size. The boxed object wraps the trait object, so it has a fixed size. How to modify this code? I have to dynamically generate boxed trait object on demand.

Comment: Type parameters are `Sized` by default, try adding `Allocator: ?Sized`.

Comment: Move the generic constraints from the `struct` declaration to the `impl`, i.e.: `struct C<Allocator> {…}` (no constraints) and `impl<Allocator: MyTrait + ?Sized> C<Allocator> {…}`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/66369912/5397009

Comment: @Jmb Though in this case, the `?Sized` bound is necessary on the struct, too.

Comment: @FZs right, negative bounds are required on the `struct` if you want to be able to apply them to an `impl`

Answer (score 0):

The type of `boxed_value` in `main()` is `Box<dyn MyTrait>`, which is a **fat** pointer because of `dyn`.
But `C::new()` expects a `Box<Allocator>` where `Allocator` is a **concrete** type (implementing `MyTrait`), i.e. a *normal* pointer (not **fat**) because no virtual-table is needed here.

Even if a `Box<dyn MyTrait>` actually points toward a `A`, it is not the same type as `Box<A>`.
Moreover, you cannot go back from a `dyn` type to a concrete type (except by downcasting with [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html), which implies a runtime check).

I think you could simply use `dyn MyTrait` all along the way in `C`.

```rust
struct C {
    a: Box<dyn MyTrait>,
}

impl C {
    pub fn new(a: Box<dyn MyTrait>) -> Self {
        Self { a }
    }
}
```

---

I probably misunderstood the intention behind `C`.
I thought the (dynamic) polymorphism relied only on `boxed_value` but if another level of (static) polymorphism is *also* needed on `C`, then the original code with `+ ?Sized` in the implementation is probably much better (as stated in the comments).

(I let this answer visible in case it corresponds to the intended usage; I will delete it if the author of the question confirms that I'm totally wrong.)

Comment: OP's generic version does (almost) work, it's just that they didn't add a `?Sized` bound. And then they can have `Allocator` be `dyn MyTrait`, because `dyn MyTrait` is a type that satisfies the `Allocator: MyTrait` bound.