# Where do you see Trait requirements in docs?

Tags: rust

For example, where do you see what Traits are required on K, V, and S for HashMap<K, V, S>?

There seem to be a few sites: crates.io, doc.rust-lang.org, and docs for packages. Where do each of these show you the Traits required?

Comment: You see them right under the struct definition on docs.rs. If you're wondering why there aren't any trait bounds shown for `HashMap<K, V, S>`, that's because there aren't any. Methods are split on a per-`impl` basis, so the ones that require Hashability start [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#impl-HashMap%3CK,+V,+S%3E-1).

Comment: rustdoc shows trait bounds clearly. Where are you missing them?

Comment: Something which might be confusing at first glance is that in Rust it's pretty conventional to put trait bounds on *methods* rather than *structures*. So you can in fact create a hashmap over arbitrary types basically without restrictions, but you probably won't be able to use that map in any useful way. The main reason is that trait bounds on structs have to be repeated in every impl block so they're annoying, the second is that it creates unnecessary limitations or requires unnecessary parameters. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66369912/8182118 is a more extensive exploration of this.

Answer (score 3):

Docs are generally hosted on either

- `doc.rust-lang.org` for crates distributed as part of Rust (`std`/`alloc`/`core`, `proc_macro`, etc.), or
- `docs.rs` for crates distributed on `crates.io`.<sup>1</sup>

Both are generated using rustdoc, which structures docs to be similar to the original code. So if a trait bound appears on a type definition:

```rust
struct Foo<T: SomeTrait> {
    // ...
}
```

...the same bound will be shown along with the type definition on its doc page.

Trait bounds can also appear in function definitions:

```rust
fn bar<T: SomeTrait>(val: T) { /* ... */ }
```

Similarly, these will show in the function signature in Rustdoc.

Finally, trait bounds can appear on `impl` blocks:

```rust
impl<T: SomeTrait> Baz<T> {
    // method definitions, etc.
}
```

Rustdoc groups items defined in the same `impl` block. For instance, the docs for [`HashMap::get()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) appear in [this impl block](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#impl-HashMap%3CK,+V,+S%3E-1):

```rust
impl<K, V, S> HashMap<K, V, S>where
    K: Eq + Hash,
    S: BuildHasher,
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> `docs.rs` also redirects e.g. `docs.rs/std` to the appropriate `doc.rust-lang.org` page.</sup>

Comment: So do you have to check many different places to collect all the trait bounds? Is there a complete list of places I should check, including each of the methods I want to use?

Comment: @Test If you are trying to use a method, you need to check the method and the impl block it's in. If you are trying to use a trait, you only need the `impl _ for _` block. If you are building the struct with [struct expression syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/struct-expr.html), you only need to check the struct definition.