# Avoid `PhantdomData` when wrapping a generic `Fn`?

Tags: rust

The following definition fails with an error that `T` is an unused parameter:

```rust
struct Wrapper<F:Fn(T)->(),T> {
    func: F
}
```

The normal solution would be to use `PhantomData` to resolve this (which is fine).  But I am curious whether there is any way to avoid using `PhantomData` in this case?

Comment: It's been a long-running quirk of the Rust compiler that `PhantomData` must be used to make type variables count as "used". For what it's worth, `PhantomData` is a zero-sized type, so it's completely optimized out and is zero-overhead at runtime, but it's still an annoyance

Comment: Yes, it means one cannot neatly construct with `Wrapper{func}`!!

Comment: The normal solution is to [not put trait bounds on structs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/6274355)

Comment: In particular, [this works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=72616785d84e17dcf13f1b1a20e3f90a)