# Implement partially overlapping traits on polymorphic collection if members all implement trait?

Tags: rust

I've got an AST structure for `IR`, and another for `Data`. Each of these consist of mostly the same types nodes, but each have some nodes which only belong in them. In general `IR` can contain logical operations like `IfThenElse` or function application, while `Data` has to be simpler records. (But, don't assume `Data` is a strict subset of `IR` - the full problem is more complicated.)

I want to have these trees type as `IR` if and only if everything within them types as `IR`. I can do this for all of the nodes with a fixed number of children, but not for dynamically sized ones such as `List`.

```
trait AST{} //Super trait that includes everything we're describing
trait IR{} //Tree that includes logic and operations
trait Data{} //Tree that only includes static data
```

To avoid a great deal of redundancy, I want to specify each type of node once, and then have them belong variably to `IR`, `Data` or both. For simple nodes, easy enough:

```
//Literals can appear in any tree:
enum Literal{
    Int(i32),
    Bool(bool)
}
impl AST for Literal {}
impl Data for Literal {}
impl IR for Literal {}

//Variables can only appear in IR, not Data:
struct Variable(String);
impl AST for Variable {}
impl IR for Variable {}

//Assume we also have a type that is only valid as Data, not IR:
struct DataItem();
impl AST for DataItem {}
impl Data for DataItem {}
```

We also have nodes containing other nodes:

```
//IfThenElse is only IR, so the struct itself can have type requirements:
struct IfThenElse<Cond, Then, Else>(
    Cond,
    Then,
    Else
);
impl<Cond : AST + IR, Then :  AST + IR, Else :  AST + IR> AST for IfThenElse<Cond , Then, Else> {}
impl<Cond : AST + IR, Then :  AST + IR, Else :  AST + IR> IR for IfThenElse<Cond , Then, Else> {}

//Tuples can be valid IR, Data, or both, depending on their children:
struct Tuple<T1, T2>(T1, T2);
impl<T1 : AST, T2 : AST> AST for Tuple<T1, T2>{}
impl<T1 : IR + AST, T2 : IR + AST> IR for Tuple<T1, T2>{}
impl<T1 : Data + AST, T2 : Data + AST> Data for Tuple<T1, T2>{}
```

So far everything works exactly as I want it to, as the following code demonstrates:

```
//Functions to assert that the type checking actually works:
fn accept_ir<T : IR>(t : &T){}
fn accept_data<T : Data>(t : &T){}
fn accept_ast<T : AST>(t : &T){}

fn tuple_type_check() {
    //Tuple with a Variable beneath it is IR:
    let ir_t  = Tuple(
        Variable("x".to_string()),
        Literal::Int(1)
    );
    accept_ir(&ir_t);

    //Tuple with only literals is both IR and Data:
    let both_t  = Tuple(
        Literal::Int(1),
        Literal::Bool(true)
    );
    accept_ir(&both_t);
    accept_data(&both_t);

    //Tuples can be nested, and the type checking will still work:
    let nested_ir_t  = Tuple(
        IfThenElse(
            Literal::Bool(true),
            Literal::Int(1),
            Literal::Int(2)
        ),
        Literal::Int(5)
    );
    accept_ir(&nested_ir_t);

    //And it knows all of these are AST:
    accept_ast(&ir_t);
    accept_ast(&both_t);
    accept_ast(&nested_ir_t);

    //Tuples which contain a mix of Data-only and IR-only items are neither:
    let malformed_t  = Tuple(
        DataItem(),
        Variable("x".to_string()),
    );
    
    // accept_ir(&malformed_t); //Won't compile (as it shouldn't)
    // accept_data(&malformed_t);
}
```

In the above, you can see that `Tuple` nodes type as `Data` when their children are `Data` and `IR` when their children are `IR`, and that this works recursively for nested trees.

Where I hit a wall is when I try to get the same behavior for types with a dynamic collection within them:

```
struct List<T>(
    Vec<T>
);
impl Data for List<Box<dyn Data>> {}
impl IR for List<Box<dyn IR>> {}
impl AST for List<Box<dyn AST>> {}

fn list_type_check() {
    //A list of only data is data...
    let data_l: List<Box<dyn Data>>  = List( //..but I have to explicitly declare it as a Data list
        vec![Box::new(Literal::Int(1)), Box::new(DataItem())]
    );
    accept_data(&data_l);

    //A list of literals should be Data AND IR
    let both_l: List<Box<dyn Data>>  = List( //..but I have pick just one to declare it as
        vec![Box::new(Literal::Int(1)), Box::new(Literal::Int(2))]
    );
    accept_data(&both_l);
    //accept_ir(&both_l); //and the other one won't compile..

    //Nesting works, but I have to declare the inner list as a list of dyn IR/Data too:
    let inner_l: List<Box<dyn IR>> = List(
        vec![
            Box::new(Variable("x".to_string())),
            Box::new(Variable("y".to_string())),
        ]
    );
    let outer_l : List<Box<dyn IR>> = List(
        vec![
            Box::new(inner_l),
            Box::new(Variable("l".to_string())),
        ]
    );
    accept_ir(&outer_l);
    
    //And none of these are also AST:
    // accept_ast(&data_l);
    // accept_ast(&both_l);
    // accept_ast(&outer_l);
}
```

This doesn't completely fail, but:

- Every node has to be explicitly declared (nice inference is gone)
- It breaks if I try to make `AST` a supertrait (`trait IR: AST {}`)
- Values can't belong to both traits, even if their contents meet the requirements

I also suspect there are a bunch of ways that would let me make take one step, but shackle me in ways that make this structure substantially less useful going forward.

Comment: Can you store your list items in an enum and then dispatch on the variant? That's a common technique for heterogenous lists.

Comment: @BallpointBen I'm unclear what you mean - are you saying the list would store something of an enum type? What would the variants of the enum you're imagining be?

Comment: One variant per heterogenous type.

Comment: The way to store multiple types in a collection is trait objects. This can be slightly improved by having the `impl Data` for a generic `T: Data` and `impl<T: Data + ?Sized> Data for Box<T>`.

Comment: Unrelated, but [don't put trait bounds on the struct unless absolutely necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229332/should-trait-bounds-be-duplicated-in-struct-and-impl).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman So I just rewrote the question for greater clarity, not sure if you saw that. Agree on not putting trait in struct bounds, mostly just did that to make the shape clearer to readers. I'm confused about "`impl Data` for a generic `T: Data`" - is that a typo? It looks like a circular requirement.

Comment: I meant for `List`.

Comment: Why does it break if you put `AST` a supertrait of `IR`?

Comment: If I add `trait IR : AST{}`, then `impl IR for List<Box<dyn IR>> {}` complains that `the trait bound `typed_value::List<Box<(dyn IR + 'static)>>: AST` is not satisfied`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do much to regain nice inference, but you can have a method `fn new_data(v: Vec<Box<dyn Data>>) -> List<Box<dyn Data>>` to avoid having to put type annotations in the code.

A nice improvement is instead of implementing `Data` for `Box<dyn Data>` (same for other traits), you can impl it generically for `T: Data`. This way, you can also put homogeneous lists more efficiently. To allow using `Box<dyn Data>`, you need to add an `impl<T: Data + ?Sized> Data for Box<T>`.

This also solves the second problem, since now you implement `AST` generically, `List<Box<dyn Data>>` also impls `AST`.

For the third problem, you can create a trait `DataAndIr: Data + IR` and a blanket implementation `impl<T: Data + IR> DataAndIr for T`. Then, you can store `Box<dyn DataAndIr>`.

Putting it all together:

```
trait AST{}
trait IR : AST{}
trait Data : AST{}
struct List<T>(
    Vec<T>
);

impl<T : AST> AST for List<T> {}
impl<T: AST + ?Sized> AST for Box<T>{}
impl<T : Data> Data for List<T> {}
impl<T : Data + ?Sized> Data for Box<T>{}
impl<T : IR> IR for List<T> {}
impl<T: IR + ?Sized> IR for Box<T>{}
trait DataAndIr : Data + IR{}
impl<T : Data + IR> DataAndIr for T{}

//Helper functions to reduce boilerplate type declarations
fn data_list(v: Vec<Box<dyn Data>>) -> List<Box<dyn Data>> {
    List(v)
}
fn ir_list(v: Vec<Box<dyn IR>>) -> List<Box<dyn IR>> {
    List(v)
}


fn list_type_check() {
    let data_l = data_list( // function saves us from writing the type, at keast
        vec![Box::new(Literal::Int(1)), Box::new(DataItem())]
    );
    accept_data(&data_l);

    // A list of literals can be Data AND IR
    let both_l : List<Box<dyn DataAndIr>> = List(  //Need to declare it as both (or use a function) but it works
        vec![Box::new(Literal::Int(1)), Box::new(Literal::Int(2))]
    );
    accept_data(&both_l);
    accept_ir(&both_l);

    //Nesting still works:
    let outer_l = ir_list(
        vec![
            Box::new(ir_list(
                vec![
                    Box::new(Variable("x".to_string())),
                    Box::new(Variable("y".to_string())),
                ]
            )),
            Box::new(Variable("l".to_string())),
        ]
    );
    accept_ir(&outer_l);
    
    //And everything type checks as AST:
    accept_ast(&data_l);
    accept_ast(&both_l);
    accept_ast(&outer_l);
}
```

Comment: Is the second paragraph supposed to say "instead of implementing `Data` for `List<Box<dyn Data>>` you can impl it generically for `List<T : Data>`"?

Comment: @EdwardPeters Yes (assuming you `impl<T: Data + ?Sized> Data for Box<T>`).

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "now you implement `AST` generically"? Follow the same pattern as `Data`, with `impl<T : AST> AST for List<T> {}` and `impl<T: AST + ?Sized> AST for Box<T>{}`?

Comment: @EdwardPeters Yes.

Comment: Wonderful - hope you don't mind, I edited the working version into your answer, just in case it makes it a little clearer for the next guy.