# How to initialize fileds of generic struct from functions returning impl Trait?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have a struct with a field of generic type and a function that returns an `impl Trait`. I need to initialize this field with the result of the function, but the compiler doesn't recognize that the types are compatible ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a39562111b503ab68baf47a7f39395e4)):

```rust
trait Trait {}

struct St {}

impl Trait for St {}

fn ret_impl() -> impl Trait {
    St {}
}

struct Generic<T: Trait> {
    field: T,
}

impl<T: Trait> Generic<T> {
    fn new() -> Generic<T> {
        Generic { field: ret_impl() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let var = Generic::new();
}
```

This gives me an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:21:20
   |
7  | fn ret_impl() -> impl Trait {
   |                  ---------- the found opaque type
...
18 | impl<T: Trait> Generic<T> {
   |      - expected this type parameter
...
21 |             field: ret_impl()
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found opaque type
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                 found opaque type `impl Trait`
   = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

This is puzzling for me because compile knows that ret_impl() returns something that implements Trait an the field may contain somethings that implements Trait. So what's the problem to assign one to the other? It seems that I'm missing something obvious.

Is it possible to make it work or it is impossible to express if like this in Rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cdhowie explanation is correct, but it doesn't explain what to do if you really want `impl Trait`. The solution is to return `impl Trait` in `new()` too:

```rust
impl Generic<()> {
    fn new() -> Generic<impl Trait> {
        Generic {
            field: ret_impl(),
        }
    }
}
```

In the `impl` header I put `()`, since if you make it generic you will have to specify it as inference will fail to deduce it. This won't work if you put `T: Trait` on the struct, but [you should not do it anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229332/should-trait-bounds-be-duplicated-in-struct-and-impl).

Comment: Returning `impl Trait` works indeed! But `impl Generic<()>` won't work since the trait bound is not satisfied.

Comment: @yesint That's why I said you should remove the `T: Trait` bound from the struct.

Comment: Oh, I got it! Yes, you are right, this works.

Comment: What still looks weird for me is that `Generic<()>` actually has a field of type `impl Trait` instead of `()` as it should be according to Generic definition. Is empty type somehow special in this respect?

Comment: @yesint No, the implementation is of type `Generic<()>`, i.e. it contains the `new()` method, but the `new()` method returns `Generic<impl Trait>`, a different type. Like any method can return something that is not `Self`.

Comment: @yesint It may look weird for a constructor, but constructors in Rust are just a convention, nothing special about them.

Comment: Yes, sure, now I understand. This is actually very logical. I'm a bit corrupted by C++ :)

Answer (score 3):

What you're missing is that `ret_impl` decides what its return type is (`St`) but the *caller* of `Generic::new()` decides what `T` is, and that can be *any* type implementing `Trait`. When that type is not exactly `St`, then you would have a type mismatch.

`let var = Generic::new();` will also fail to compile because you haven't told it what `T` is, and any type implementing `Trait` would satisfy the bound.

It seems like you might want `ret_impl` to be a function of `Trait` instead:

```
trait Trait {
    fn ret_impl() -> Self;
}

struct St {}

impl Trait for St {
    fn ret_impl() -> Self {
        St {}
    }
}

//-------------------

struct Generic<T: Trait> {
    field: T,
}

impl<T: Trait> Generic<T> {
    fn new() -> Generic<T> {
        Generic { field: T::ret_impl() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let var: Generic<St> = Generic::new();
}
```

Comment: I understand the problem with type determination on the caller side, but I can't fidure out how to express this correctly. Your solution unfortunately won't work for me because the API requires that the function should return the `impl Trait`.

Comment: @yesint Then you're going to have to provide more information so that we understand the problem better. The compiler cannot make the opaque type behind the `impl Trait` work for all `T: Trait`.