# Why is phantom data not auto inferred?

Tags: rust

So this is apparently a [well-known issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/16reqd6/hot_take_phantomdata_should_not_be_necessary/), but the explanations have been above my understanding.  So just to be concrete, here is the code that I wish would work:

```
trait Data<T> {
    fn get(&self) -> T;
}

struct S<T, SD> where SD: Data<T>{
    d: SD,
}

impl<T, SD> S<T, SD> where SD: Data<T> {
    fn d_get(&self) -> T {
        self.d.get()
    }
}
```

But since type parameter `T` does not appear inside `S`, the compiler asks me to put a phantom data in it.  Surely if you add phantom data, it works.  From what I understood from the comments in the earlier linked reddit post is that such an auto-inferring can cause issues for lifetime parameters.  I would really appreciate if someone can explain this in a language that does not need type theory, or please point me to some blog post or a resource that teaches the requisite type theory needed to understand it.  (Sorry for the second parenthetical question: I just started to read Benjamin Pierce's Types and Programming Languages mainly towards understanding subtleties in Rust like this one.  Is it an overkill?)

Comment: The tl;dr is that you could do `PhantomData<T>` or `PhantomData<&'static T>` or `PhantomData<*const T>` or `PhantomData<fn() -> T>` and so on. These can mean different things, particularly with regards to drop checking, so inferring the wrong one could actually cause your type to behave in ways it shouldn't.

Comment: @cdhowie Not just drop checking, also variance (this was the original motivation AFAIK) and auto traits.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Right, it wasn't supposed to be an exhaustive list. Just one example.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/6274355

Comment: Thanks, everyone!  I also found something useful (Crust of Rust video link in a reddit comment): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVYWDIW71jk&t=4374s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before explaining why inference doesn't happen here, I will point out that your struct definition doesn't depend on `T` at all.  You only use it in a bound, but the bound isn't required to define the shape of the struct either.  [Unless your struct definition requires a certain bound, you should not include it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/501250). Simply removing the bound and the `T` generic type argument therefore solves your problem.

---

The simplest way to explain why phantom data inference doesn't happen is to point out that these phantom data types are all perfectly reasonable but do very different things:

- `PhantomData<T>`
- `PhantomData<&T>`
- `PhantomData<*const T>`
- `PhantomData<fn() -> T>`

This is not an exhaustive list, either! Choosing the wrong one can cause drop safety problems as well as cause the type argument to have the wrong variance or make your type `!Send` and `!Sync` when it otherwise could be.  It is therefore not feasible to have the compiler choose for you.

Further reading:

- [PhantomData - The Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/phantom-data.html#phantomdata)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Yes, the `T` bound is unnecessary in the struct, but removing it still doesn't work without phantom data.  How to do the `impl` block without `T`?  The following does not work.
`trait Data<T> {fn get(&self) -> T;}
struct S<SD>{d: SD}

impl<T, SD> S<SD> where SD: Data<T> {fn d_get(&self) ->T{self.d.get()}} 
`

Comment: @bkc4 Will one type implement multiple instances of `Data` with different generic arguments? If not, changing `Data` to use an associated type instead of a generic argument solves that: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=32710bc19d6206a749a42d9a54852ea5

Comment: The real case is quite complicated (it's code at my company I cannot share); I tried to distill the issue in the smallest example possible.  As you said, it will be used for multiple monomorphizations w.r.t `T`, so cannot use associated types.

Comment: @bkc4 Another option is to provide `d_get` with a trait instead of an inherent impl. In this simple case you can just implement `Data<T>` on `S<SD>`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a71ee138e2457779c97d70071235c0a3 -- If you can't implement this trait, you can always create another trait and implement that instead: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=15eeeb861b9f870686fbe83001763859 -- And, of course, you can keep the original code and use `PhantomData` if neither of these are feasible.

Comment: @bkc4 If the purpose of `S` here is to be a newtype that "tags" the inner value with a particular `T`, then the bound does make sense on `S` -- and I've had to do similar things before myself. In this case, I believe the phantom data type that makes the most sense is `PhantomData<fn() -> T>`.

Comment: Thanks for these examples!  Unfortunately in my case I don't see any other solution than phantom data without complicating it more than it already is.  I have a struct containing a field of type parameter, say `S`.  Now I need to implement a trait, say `I` for this struct only for those types `S` that implement another trait, say `D`, that has several generic type parameters, one of which is, say, `M`.  And I want the associated type in `impl I` for the struct to be equal to `M`.

Comment: @bkc4 Yep, sometimes you just can't get away from needing phantom data, and that's totally fine! It's just always good to prove that you need it by trying alternative approaches.