# Default type parameters on Rust structs: is it possible to provide a default type containing a lifetime?

Tags: generics, rust, borrow-checker, higher-kinded-types, generic-associated-types

I'm (unfortunately) suspecting that what I'd like to do is impossible, so I'm very open to best-practice workarounds.

In short, I've got a setup like the following:

```rust
pub struct OffsetMod<'a> {
    kind: OffsetKind,
    composition: ChemicalComposition<'a>,
}
```

Most of the time, that struct should indeed be the owner of that `ChemicalComposition`, but sometimes this data is stored differently, and the struct is peeled apart into something approximating `HashMap<ChemicalComposition<'a>, OffsetKind>`, then I have a method that iterates over this `HashMap` and returns a series of reconstituted `OffsetMod<'a>`s. Well, sorta `OffsetMod<'a>`s... Obviously the only way I could get those owned `ChemicalComposition`s back (without some very expensive `.clone()`ing) is to drain / move the `HashMap`, but that's not something I want to do.

Downstream, I actually only need a reference to those `ChemicalCompositions`, so really what I want to return is a sort of borrowed `OffsetMod<'a>` — something like:

```rust
pub struct BorrowedOffsetMod<'a> {
    kind: OffsetKind,
    composition: &'a ChemicalComposition<'a>,
}
```

The issue, however, with creating that second struct, is that I'd now have to duplicate all of the methods / trait impls I have for `OffsetMod` for `BorrowedOffsetMod`!

Elsewhere in my code, when encountering a similar case of needing a struct to come in a form that borrows its contents, and another that doesn't, I wrote something like this:

```rust
pub struct Target<S = String> {
    pub group: S,
    pub location: Option<S>,
    pub residue: Option<S>,
}
```

By default, it owns its data (`String`s, in this case), but my impl blocks are written as:

```rust
impl<S: Borrow<str>> Target<S> {
    // — snip —
}
```

In this way, I can typically assume that `Target` owns its data, but I can also "borrow" `Target` as `Target<&'a str>`, and all of the same methods will work fine because of the `Borrow<str>` bound.

**Now here comes my very troubling issue:**

If I try the same with my `OffsetMod` struct, the pain begins:

```rust
pub struct OffsetMod<'a, C = ChemicalComposition<'a>> {
    kind: OffsetKind,
    composition: C,
}
```

Which hits me with the ever-awful

```
error[E0392]: parameter `'a` is never used
help: consider removing `'a`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `PhantomData`
```

Now, to open with the "best" solution I've found so far, I'm a bit perplexed at why this is so easy and works fine:

```rust
pub type OffsetMod<'a> = OffsetModInner<ChemicalComposition<'a>>;
struct OffsetModInner<C> {
    kind: OffsetKind,
    composition: C,
}
```

When that feels quite a lot like what I'd expect `OffsetMod<'a, C = ChemicalComposition<'a>>` to do behind the scenes... The reason this solution isn't quite cutting it for me, is that it now "splits" my type in two: my parameters may be able to use `OffsetMod<'a>` just fine, but for the borrowed version, I can't do `OffsetMod<&ChemicalComposition<'a>>`, but I need to use that second "hidden" `OffsetModInner<&ChemicalComposition<'a>>` or make another alias like `BorrowedOffsetMod<'a>`. Whilst this is the best I can land on, it still feels a bit messy. **EDIT:** Slightly more than messy, what I've written is invalid, since the `OffsetModInner` *cannot* be private if the `type OffsetMod` containing it is public! I'd have to leak that `OffsetKindInner` into public API.

Now, I understand that Rust wants this `'a` bound to show up in a field somewhere, so that if you're *not* using the default type, it still knows how to populate that lifetime. Perhaps we could claim that `C` always lives as long as `'a`, since `C` always shows up in the `Composition` field.

```rust
pub struct OffsetMod<'a, C: 'a = ChemicalComposition<'a>> {
    kind: OffsetKind,
    composition: C,
}
```

But no dice there either — same error as before. Though I've tried a multitude of other things, I've not found one I'm pleased with:

1. `PhantomData` looks and feels hacky, and I'm not certain if it's semantically correct either? I don't know, perhaps I'm more open to this one than I thought...
2. Something like `Cow<'a, ChemicalComposition<'a>>` feels a bit nasty and adds runtime overhead where there really doesn't need to be. I'll only ever need references (no need to copy), it's just that these `OffsetMod` structs are sometimes the only place the underlying data has to live (e.g. for `ChemicalComposition`s that *aren't* stored in that `HashMap`)!
3. I tried some unholy GAT stuff with a `Borrow`esque trait that looked like this:

```rust
pub trait NestedBorrow<T> {
    type Content<'a>
    where
        Self: 'a;

    fn borrow(&self) -> &T;
}

impl<T> NestedBorrow<T> for T {
    type Content<'a> = T
    where
        Self: 'a;

    fn borrow(&self) -> &T {
        self
    }
}

impl<T> NestedBorrow<T> for &T {
    type Content<'a> = T
    where
        Self: 'a;

    fn borrow(&self) -> &T {
        &**self
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct OffsetMod<'a, C: NestedBorrow<ChemicalComposition<'a>> + 'a = ChemicalComposition<'a>> {
    kind: OffsetKind,
    composition: C::Content<'a>,
}
```

But that leaks `NestedBorrow` into the public API for `OffsetMod` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66369912), caused problems with `&ChemicalComposition<'_>` not being accepted by `OffsetKind` — it was always looking for the owned `ChemicalComposition<'_>` version, something I never figured out — and it's generally revolting.

What do you think, is it possible to do better than the `type` aliases? Is there some Rust pattern that's better suited for structs that sometimes own, and sometimes borrow data — whilst keeping my `impl` blocks unified with `impl<T: Borrow<ChemicalComposition<'a>>> OffsetMod<'a, T>`?

Comment: Why not just remove the default from `C` and provide type aliases for the common cases?

Comment: As I wrote above, that is indeed the "best" solution I have come up with — the primary problem was the splitting / duplication of the type names! I couldn't use the nice `OffsetMod` name for both the public alias and the underlying struct. It's especially annoying because that `InnerOffsetMod` has to be part of the public API if the alias is. Then I'd need a newtype to hide that, but then it's back to losing or duplicating all of the impls!

Comment: I'm saying you make the struct public and also provide a public type aliases to cover the two usual cases for the sake of convenience. There's no reason the struct needs to be private. E.g. `pub struct OffsetMod`, `pub type OwnedOffsetMod`, `pub type BorrowedOffsetMod`.

Comment: `PhantomData` can work, but I also believe the best way to go is type aliases.